# process parallel requests in Apache web server

Tags: php, apache

My VPS can't process two parallel request at the same time, I have a `php` file and here is its content:

```
<?php
sleep(5);
echo time();
?>
```

when I run this script from two different browser tabs, both of them should return `CURRENT TIME` + `5` but the first tab returns `CURRENT TIME`+`5` and the second tab returns `CURRENT TIME`+`10`, It show that my web server processes the requests one by one, not at the same time, how can I solve that?
thanks.

Comment: the time to open new tab and execute will add some second , you need add echo time(); on top to see the diffrent

Comment: this problem happens everywhere, even in telegram bot's php file, it doesn't run the second request until the first second become compeleted.

Comment: what server side platform u use ?

Comment: you mean the webserver? Apache 2.4

Comment: server plat form linux ?

Comment: sorry, Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

You need To execute tabs on background to avoid waiting .

first Page php will be :

```
<?php
$er=getopt('code:');

sleep(5);


file_put_contents ('/tmp/'.$er['code'].".tsv",time());
?>
```

Second Page :

```
<?php

pclose(popen("php /home/firstpage.php -code ".$_POST['code']."  >/dev/null &", 'r'));

?>
```

Third Page this one will call from browser by interval function :

```
<?php

$result=file_get_content('/tmp/'.$_POST['code'].".tsv");

echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: I think my problem is in Apache Config